# iCloud storage doesn't add up on in iPhone's "Manage Storage" panel

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, storage

I'm looking at the "Manage Storage" panel, (accessible from Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage) which shows a list of all the items being backed up along with a total. Or at least that's what it appears to be... the problem is that the total shown is about 50 times greater than the sum of its parts. Like this:

[image: the Manage Storage screen]

All the listed apps together add up to less than 60 MB, but it insists that is using (and will continue to use) 3.3 GB.

Is this normal? Is there 3.2 GB of unlisted overhead? Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: You have to tap "Show all apps...".

Comment: Of course I did that. Except for Camera Roll they are listed in decreasing order by size. The total for ALL the apps is under 60MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several days after I posted this question my phone started having problems (apps opening slowly and crashing) and I erased the phone and attempted to restore from the iCloud backup. The restore screen gave me a time estimate of 11 hours for a process that (for most people) takes about 10 minutes. It ran for about an hour and then failed with an error message that the wifi connection had failed (it hadn't).

After numerous unsuccessful attempts and several days of escalating phone support from Apple, a senior tech told me that my backup was "corrupted" and forwarded the request on to an engineer to see if my data could be retrieved.

So I believe the correct answer here is that this was not normal and was a sign that the phone contained some sort of corrupted data, which was being passed on to iCloud every time I backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts, messages, mails, calendar, settings, bookmarks, wallpaper, ringtones … are also included in the backup. ([Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859))

Comment: It seems unlikely that all of that together could account for a 3.1 GB discrepancy.